# /etc/cron.d Not working under debian

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I can't seem to get anything inside of the cron.d folder working. I need to be able to drop cron files inside or as least just get one file working that I can edit. Currently the folder has a "php5" file that already works but my other files wont run. I made the file the same permissions as the "php5" file (644 root:root)

This is my current cron file under /etc/cron.d/mycron

```
* * * * *   root    /usr/bin/php /var/www/private/cron/checkstatus.php
```

Is there some kind of magicaly hidden file I need to my cron file to?

Running debian 7.5.0 minimal server install.

Comment: Have you looked at the log files that your cron daemon is writing?  There may be clues there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thank you Stephen, it was simpler than I though. I checked the logs

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep cron -i
```

And I found this

```
ERROR (Missing newline before EOF, this crontab file will be ignored)
```

Adding a newline to the end of my crontab files fixed the problem. On top of that I had a return carriage character from Windows that was causing bash to choke.